# React event handler works without bind()

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, bind

I'm working through a react tutorial and the instructor is showing that the event handler in this code won't work, because this() is accessing the outer environment. But I get no error. Can someone explain it to me?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  handleIncrement() {
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement()}>
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Benedikt! You are invoking `this.handleIncrement` directly on render. You want to give `onClick` a function that should be invoked when the event occurs instead, e.g `() => this.handleIncrement()`

Comment: But why it works for me event with non-arrow function?

Comment: It doesn't. You are calling the function with the `()` directly on render which will give you the correct `this`, but that's not what you want to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm talking about this() in console.log(this.state).

Comment: Please read my previous comments again. You are *invoking `this.handleIncrement` directly on render by writing `this.handleIncrement()`*. This is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, when your event handler needs to access `this` from a local scope, and you call the method like this; `this.handleClick()`, you are telling JavaScript to implement the task of the method IMMEDIATELY it gets there (in your case, immediately it is rendered), which conventionally, doesn't require binding to `this`.

But when you 'call' (I put it in quotations because the right word should be REFER) a method like this; `this.handleClick`, you are actually referring to the method (meaning it should be invoked only when the user does something), not invoking it immediately. This either requires binding `this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this);` or the use of arrow function for your method `handleClick = () => {};`. It is mostly used for `onClick` functionalities.

You are not getting that error in your code because you included the parentheses - `this.handleIncrement()`. If you remove the parentheses and still `consoleLog` `this.state` in your `handleIncrement`, you will definitely get `undefined` error. But if your `handleIncrement` is only logging something outside a state, you will not get the error.

If you understand my basic explanation, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: Perfectly written, as a beginner, I can very well say that this answer solved my doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Any function called *directly* from render method will get the container object as `this`
But when we assign a function to `onClick` event, we don't want to call that function immediately... so we assign it like this

```
<button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>
```

(only the function name without `()` at the end) ... and this says to call the function when the button is clicked.

But when you click the button the function will not be called from the `render` method anymore so the `this` reference will be changed and produce an error.

In your case, you added the `()` to your `this.handleIncrement` function invoking it immediately... so it's not causing any problem but it will give you wrong results in almost all cases since it won't get called on `click` but it will get called with each render.

Since your *simple* code gets rendered only on button click it's probably correcting the problem. **Add a second button** and it will give wrong result or the UI will freeze.

The correct way is to remove the `()` after `this.handleIncreament` and bind the function inside **constructor** ... `this.handleIncreament = this.handleIncreament.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Without bind() method you can use directly arrow function in handleincrement.
check below code

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { count: 0 };
  

  handleIncrement=()=> {
    const { count } = this.state;
    this.setState({ count: count + 1 });
  }

  render () {
    return <label>
      <div>Count {this.state.count}</div>
      <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
    </label>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.querySelector('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main/>
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Afzal Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2215944/afzal-hossain).

```
<button onClick={this.handleIncrement()}>
```

This line will call `handleIncrement` function on render. This is not the correct way to add an event.

```
<button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>
```

This will be the correct approach to call the function. But since it's a callback, it will have no knowledge of what `this` is since it's not in the same context.

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) makes it really clear why we should always bind callback functions with `this` to have the context available in that particular function.

However, if you don't want to bind your function, there are two workarounds mentioned in react documentation

**Public Class Fields syntax**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

handleIncrement = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.querySelector('main'));
```

**Arrow functions**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

handleIncrement() {
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}>
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

For more details, refer to this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) link.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the arrow function way, since this answer isn't at the top, and BTW I needed to understand the arrow function way since it's used in the react tic-tak-toe tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As [Afzal Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380198/1541563) says, you're invoking `this.handleIncrement()` when the element renders rather than when the button is clicked.

You need to provide the function handle itself to `onClick`, and [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to the correct context when it is constructed, so that [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) always accesses the instance of `Counter` within `handleIncrement()`.

Here is a working implementation of the suggestions made in his answer:

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { count: 0 };
  handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this);

  handleIncrement () {
    const { count } = this.state;
    this.setState({ count: count + 1 });
  }

  render () {
    return <label>
      <div>Count {this.state.count}</div>
      <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
    </label>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.querySelector('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main/>
```